# Azure table storage retrieve operation returns null for a value that is not null

Tags: azure, azure-storage

This is the format of my table storage data

PartitionKey RowKey Timestamp Close Currency Date

Here is my entity object

```
public class CurrencyEntity : TableEntity
{
    public CurrencyEntity() { }
    public CurrencyEntity(string currency, string date)
    {
        Currency = currency.ToUpper();
        Date = date;

        PartitionKey = currency.ToUpper();
        RowKey = date;
    }
    public CurrencyEntity(string currency, string date, string close)
    {
        Currency = currency.ToUpper();
        Date = date;
        Close = close;

        PartitionKey = currency.ToUpper();
        RowKey = date;
    }

    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Close { get; set; }
    
}
```

This is my table service method to retrieve a currency value for a date to convert prices to USD.

```
 public async Task<decimal?> GetCurrencyValueForDate(string currency, DateTime date)
    {
        //ensure variables match key formats
        currency = currency.ToUpper();
        if (date > DateTime.Now)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var stringDate = date.ToString(CurrencyTableRowKeyFormat);
        var table = GetCloudTable(new AzureConfiguration(_config).WebsiteStorageAcctConnectionString, CurrencyTableName);
        var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CurrencyEntity>(currency, stringDate);
        var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);

        var dto = result?.Result as CurrencyEntity;
        return Convert.ToDecimal(dto?.Close);
    }
```

The retrieve operation is actually retrieving the row data BUT everytime the result variable has all the correct values EXCEPT Close is always null, despite the fact that close has a value in the table.

Note: I haven't worked on this project for about 6 months, I fairly certain this was working correctly last I worked on it. I am using the using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;

[image]

[image]

Any help appreciated.

**Note:**  ***When in doubt, reboot. Since Guarav couldn't reproduce the error AND the only answer, with my exact same code and table couldn't produce the error, the only logical conclusion is somehow my table got corrupted since this code worked a while back. I deleted the table and reimported the data and now it does work.***

Comment: Why are you doing `result?.Result`? Shouldn't `result` variable hold your entity?

Comment: And if result is null? Regardless, the data problem is PRIOR to that code being executed. Close is null in the result variable

Comment: I see. In old storage SDK the retrieve operation would throw an exception if entity is not found but they changed this behavior in the new SDK. I just tried your code and I am able to get the data properly.

Comment: Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/gmantri/bcb61923628ed5fbfe9bfef0a68a5952.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in the edited post, the row has a value in the table but the code, which is identical to yours is returning null for the Close value of result.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the data?

Comment: i did, in the edited post

Comment: You shared the table structure. I am more interested in seeing the actual data that is being stored.

Comment: There is an image of my azure storage explorer showing the row i am retrieving in the original post

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not seeing it.

Comment: its there now...not sure why it didnt work before

Comment: Thanks. I can reproduce the error :). I changed the data type of "Close" attribute in the entity (the stored entity) from "String" to "Double" and now in my code the value of "Close" is coming as null. Please check the data type of the "Close" attribute in Storage Explorer.

Comment: And how do I do that? I cant see how its done.

Comment: From what I see all properties are of type string in the current table

Comment: Please see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbu9V.png. In my case, I had set it to "Double".

Comment: Thanks for all the help, see how I got it working in the note at the end of the post.

Comment: I’m glad to hear that you’re unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, the table's structure should be like as below
[image]

My Tes Code

```
string connectionString = "";
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
            var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            var table= tableClient.GetTableReference("test");
            var retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CurrencyEntity>("USD", "2021-06-24");
            var result = await table.ExecuteAsync(retrieveOperation);

            var dto = result?.Result as CurrencyEntity;


public class CurrencyEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public CurrencyEntity() { }
        public CurrencyEntity(string currency, string date)
        {
            Currency = currency.ToUpper();
            Date = date;

            PartitionKey = currency.ToUpper();
            RowKey = date;
        }
        public CurrencyEntity(string currency, string date, string close)
        {
            Currency = currency.ToUpper();
            Date = date;
            Close = close;

            PartitionKey = currency.ToUpper();
            RowKey = date;
        }

        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Close { get; set; }

    }
```

[image]